# Cors error on service http request Angular 4

Tags: angular, rest, cors

This service make a http request to an external api  import { Injectable } from

```
'@angular/core';
import { HttpModule,Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyDataServiceService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {}

  getData(){
    return this.http.get('http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerbiostats/?PerMode=Totals&Season=2016-17&LeagueID=00&SeasonType=Playoffs');
  }

}
```

But I get that error `'solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerbiostats/?PerMode=Totals&Season=2016-17&LeagueID=00&SeasonType=Playoffs (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').'` It says that my request has been blocked ,because the CORS header is missed.

How I can fix that if I had noting to to with the backend?

Comment: You need to configure your server to respond with the expected CORS headers. Angular is not involved in CORS.

Answer (score 0):

The CORS settings  mainly have some aspect:allowed_orign\allowed_method\allowed_header。Your error tip seems to be allowed orign.
the cors settings can be added in nginx or app container.
nginx cors settings example from https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html:

```
location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
     }
}
```

Comment: I 'm  requesting an external api I dont have anything to do with the server,All I can set is the frontend

Comment: cors settings must be added in back-end envrionment